# GraphChi: get weight sum of all the edges in a graph

Tags: c++, graphchi, weighted-graph

I'm using [Graphchi](https://github.com/GraphChi/graphchi-cpp) for studying community detection algorithms on a weighted graph.
In documentation, I can't find a method for calculating the **total edge weight sum**.
Is there a way to do it?

I was thinking about a preprocessing initial phase, keeping a global variable in my GraphChiProgram class and sum the weight of edges in the update function for the vertices.
The problem is the an edge could be counted multiple time: if vertex A is neighbour of vertex B, the same edge AB would be counted two times.

For now, I'm passing the value from command line, calculating it with a separate script on my graph file, but I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sum the total weight as you propose: doing an update function that sums the edge weights. But instead of summing over all edges, sum only over in-edges (or out-edges). That way no edge is summed twice.

Comment: Alternatively, modify the preprocessor to count the sum for you.